# How to skip first 2 promise rest to resolve

Tags: javascript, promise, console, es6-promise

How to skip first 2 promise rest to resolve

```
const p1 = Promise.resolve(21);
const p2 = 110470116021;
const p3 = 'This promise to resolve';
const p4 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('Resolve');
    }, 1000);
});

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(values => { 
    console.log(values);
});
```

> I would like to skip first two promise and wanted to get rest promises
>   result how can i do that please guide
>
> Output should be (2) ["This promise to resolve", "Resolve"] instead
>   (4) [21, 110470116021, "This promise to resolve", "Resolve"]

Comment: don't put them in the array for Promise.all - or `console.log(values.slice(2))`

Comment: What do you mean by *skip* them? You don't want to wait for them to resolve or you simply want to ignore their results?

Comment: Just a side note,  `p2` and `p3` are not promises.

Comment: Do you still need to execute them? If so best option would be AKX answer.. otherwise don't add them to the array

Comment: Just another side note,.  creating promises and then ignoring them is something you can do,.  But something you need to be aware off, by doing so you have kind of created a kind of fork, as such you need to handle errors here again, they won't bubble up your promise chain.  In say nodejs in the future it will even terminate your process.  So putting all of them into `Promise.all` and just ignoring the result would be the simplest thing to do,  otherwise remember to implement error handling again on these ignored promises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, maybe just

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]).then(([r1, r2, r3, r4]) => { 
    console.log([r3, r4]);
});
```

? Naturally `p1` and `p2` will still be executed, but their values will not be used.

Answer (score 0):

When getting values destructure it and just take the promise you want.

```
var promise1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var promise2 = 42;
var promise3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
});

Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then(function([p1, p2, p3]) {
  console.log(p3);
});
// expected output: Array ["foo"]
```

Answer (score 0):

To build on AKX's answer, you could additionally use the `rest` operator in tandem with destructuring to create an iterable of every resolved promise after the first 2 like so:

```js
Promise.all([p1,p2,p3,p4,p5]).then(([discarded1,discarded2,...rest]) => {
  console.log(rest); // [p3 result, p4 result, p5 result]
})
```